# Cómo desplegar un combobox por codigo

Tags: c#

¿Es posible desplegar el combobox(previamente tiene datos) por medio de código?.

Comment: de que tipo de aplicacion se trata, es winform, wpf, web ?

Comment: ¿Has intentado o investigado algo al respecto?

Comment: windowsform, ya busqué como horas y nada man

Comment: En windows forms los `ComboBox` tienen la propiedad `DroppedDown`, basta con setearla en `true` y se desplegará..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad

[ComboBox.DroppedDown](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.droppeddown?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ComboBox_DroppedDown)

como ser

```
comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
```

por ejemplo si lo usas desde un boton seria

```
public void button1_Click(...){
    comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

al presionar el boton se deplaga el combo

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me funcionó. Saludos.